# Categories/Varieties and Monads

Tags: category-theory, abelian-groups, locally-presentable-categories

What is the **difference** of $\text{CAT}^{\mathbb T}$
from $\text{VAR}$ in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322459417_Algebra_and_local_presentability_how_algebraic_are_they_A_survey)
paper sketched below?

[image]

Comment: They are defined in the passage. Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I just want to know what is the intuitive difference between $VAR$ and $CAT^T$ i.e. easily understandable by a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Being the category of models of an algebraic theory is not itself characterized by algebraic axioms. The algebraic hull is the smallest 2-category with an algebraic description containing all categories of models of algebraic theories.

Comment: OK. What is this thing: $\text{CAT}^{\mathbb T}$ ? What are 0-cells and 1-cells of it? Then 2-cells will be all n.t., right?

Comment: I would suggest following the citation in the paper to the definition of the Eilenberg-Moore 2-category of a 2-monad. That's what the citations are there for.